# Stopping a loop after the last cell is reached

Tags: vba, excel

This piece of code detects the value in cell W14 then makes it a negative absolute value.  It should make every value that exists in column W, starting after W14 be a negative absolute value.  When I run it though, it will loop forever, making every single cell after W14 a negative absolute value even if a value does not exist there.  How can I stop the loop after the last cell with a value in it has been turned negative?

```
For Each r In Range(Range("W14"), Range("W14").End(xlDown))
    r.Value = -Abs(r.Value)
Next r
```

Answer (score 4):

It will only loop for to the end of the Worksheet if `Range("W14")` is the last non-empty cell in the column.  This is why you should use a bottom up approach.

```
For Each r In Range("W14", Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    r.Value = -Abs(r.Value)
Next r
```

Comment: This fixes my issue!  Thank you so much for your help and for explaining.  I've been trying to fiddle with this for hours...didn't realize this was the cause of it!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp).Row
    'get the last row with data on Column W

    For i = 14 To LastRow
        ws.Cells(i, "W").Value = -Abs(ws.Cells(i, "W").Value)
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: If the two methods come up with the same end result, does one offer an increase in performance over the other?  Or is it just another method of approaching the solution?  Thank you for your contribution by the way!

Comment: It's just another approach, I doubt there's an increase in performance either way, if there is it would be negligible anyways.

Comment: with `Range(Range("W14"), Range("W14").End(xlDown))` you are creating an array.  Standard for loops are quicker with Arrays than `For Each` loops